# C# foreach string array

Tags: c#

```
class DM_Matrix {
     public string[] DMInput_Name = new string[] {}; 
     public string[] DMOutput_Name = new string [] {};
     public int[] DMInput = new int[] { 99, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
     public int[] DMOutput = new int[] { 99, 1, 2, 3, 4 };              
}
        
public void Initialize() {
     foreach (var i in DM_Matrix.DMInput_Name) {
          CrestronConsole.PrintLine("[DM.Module.Input_Name" 
               + DM_Matrix.DMInput_Name[i]);
     }
}
```

Compiler error on "i":

> "(local variable) string i
>
> ERROR cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'"

I'm trying to print every the whole DM.Module.Input_Name array

I've tried to set use "int i" instead of "var i" or cast i from string to integer buy no joy. Not sure why "i" is recognised as string. In my understanding it should be recognised as "int" for the array.

Comment: You don't need to do `DM_Matrix.DMInput_Name[i]`. `i` itself is the string item coming from `DM_Matrix.DMInput_Name` collection. So you can simply do `CrestronConsole.PrintLine("[DM.Module.Input_Name" + i);`

Answer (score 3):

You are using a *foreach* loop, not a *for* loop. If this were a for loop like this:

```
foreach (var i = 0 ; i < DM_Matrix.DMInput_Name.Length ; i++)
{
    CrestronConsole.PrintLine("[DM.Module.Input_Name" +DM_Matrix.DMInput_Name[i]);
}
```

Then yes you can use `i` as an array index.

But in a foreach loop, the loop variable represents an *item of the array*, so your loop should be written like this:

```
foreach (var name in DM_Matrix.DMInput_Name) {
    CrestronConsole.PrintLine("[DM.Module.Input_Name" + name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you need to understand difference between `for` and `foreach` loop.

`for loop` : If you want to access element from an array by **index**, then use `for loop`.

`foreach loop` : If you want to iterate **through each object**, then use `foreach loop`

To solve your problem, use for loop or foreach loop, *you are mixing both loops into one.*

Solution using for loop,

```
//Use index to get value from an array
for (int i = 0; i < DM_Matrix.DMInput_Name.Length; i++)
     {
         CrestronConsole.PrintLine("[DM.Module.Input_Name" +DM_Matrix.DMInput_Name[i]);
     }
```

Solution using foreach loop

```
//Iterate over elements instead of index
foreach (var item in DM_Matrix.DMInput_Name)
     {
         CrestronConsole.PrintLine("[DM.Module.Input_Name" + item);
     }
```